# PopUp opens multiple times when selecting values from ComboBox by ArrowKey in ContactUs

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, help-center, popups

When selecting a value from the ComboBox like `I lost my password` in [ContactUs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) a PopUp opens with some further information, but the Focus is still on the ComboBox.

Now when I use the ArrowKeys `Up` and `Down` other values get selected in the ComboBox and the PopUp will open multiple times without closing previous one what results in this.

[image]

Its not a dramatic situation, cause a MouseClick anywhere will close all the PopUps, but I think either should the Focus be removed from the ComboBox or a already opened PopUp should be closed to avoid stacking of PopUps.

Comment: reproduced, on it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.4.24.2185` on meta and `2014.4.24.1564` on sites.