# Layout bug while viewing vote count in Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, design, vote-count

With [reference to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230390/221351), I notice a small alignment issue while displaying view count.

> [image]

The horizontal line separator here is not exactly in the middle.

No such issue in Stack Overflow:

> [image]

Using Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the left margin for the separator bar is off by a few pixels here on MSE.  Changing it from 15px to 10px fixes the layout:

```css
.vote-count-separator {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**Edit:** Actually, looks like:

```css
.vote-count-separator {
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

is more robust (w.r.t. large vote counts causing the column to expand), and seems to work on all sites.  This rule is now included in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14.